# how to display custom extra fee charges on frontend at orders, invoice, print totals in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, event-observer, totals

I have made an module which adds the discount and extra fee charges in the orders, invoice, print totals without overriding `collect()` and `fetch()`, I have used observer to calculate at `sales_quote_collect_totals_after`, but I am not able to figure out from where to make this free charges appears in the calculations of orders, invoice, print totals in front end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of adding custom fee in order totals:

```
<blocks>

    <sales>
        <rewrite>
            <order_totals>Spacename_Modulename_Block_Sales_Order_Totals</order_totals>
        </rewrite>
    </sales>
</blocks>
```

For **frontend order total**:

```
<?php

class Spacename_Modulename_Block_Sales_Order_Totals extends Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals
{
    /**
     * Initialize order totals array
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals
     */
    protected function _initTotals()
    {
        parent::_initTotals();
        $order_id = $this->getOrder()->getId();


        $amount = 5.00;
        if ($amount) {
            $this->addTotalBefore(new Varien_Object(array(
                'code' => 'mobielfee',
                'value' => $amount,
                'base_value' => $amount,
                'label' => $this->helper('servicecenters')->__('Shipping / Mobile installation Fee'),
            ), array('shipping', 'tax')));
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```